# Can you transfer SSD with CentOS 7 into a new PC without reinstalling?

Tags: linux, bios, centos-7, intel-graphics

I am updating a **CentOS 7** desktop from an **i5-660** on a **Gigabyte H55M** board to an **i5-12400** on a **Gigabyte B660M** using the integrated graphics as before. The original installation is at least 10 years old.

I have built the new machine and that works fine and the SATA SSD with the CentOS installation is recognised. However, it doesn't boot. Powering on goes straight to the bios.

Is there a configuration that will work with my existing installation.

I believe it is not a UEFI installation as there is no `/sys/firmware/efi`.

In `/boot` I have

```
config-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
config-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64
efi
grub
grub2
initramfs-0-rescue-6a6ac4b3411e4dd8a28e36384e0c285a.img
initramfs-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64.img
initramfs-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64.img
symvers-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64.gz
symvers-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64.gz
System.map-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
System.map-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64
vmlinuz-0-rescue-6a6ac4b3411e4dd8a28e36384e0c285a
vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64
```

`/boot/grub` contains `splash.xpm.gz`

`/boot/efi/EFI/centos/` contains

```
BOOT.CSV
BOOTX64.CSV
fonts
gcdx64.efi
grubenv
grubx64.efi
mmx64.efi
MokManager.efi
shim.efi
shimx64-centos.efi
shimx64.efi
```

And `/boot/grub2/` contains

```
device.map
fonts
grub.cfg
grubenv
i386-pc
locale
```

The grub.cfg entry for the latest build looks like this

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'CentOS Linux (3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86
_64-advanced-32eaad53-25a7-4593-a9f5-74703f7d038c' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3 --hint='hd0,msdos3'  894ed36b-faf9-46f9-acf1-46cc6179c175
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 894ed36b-faf9-46f9-acf1-46cc6179c175
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl_whitebox-root ro rd.lvm.lv=cl_whitebox/root rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64.img
}
```

I also had a look at the bios and the only settings I could find on there were

```
Boot order: SCSI-0, SCSI-1, USB-HDD
Quick boot: Enabled
S.M.A.R.T.: Disabled
SATA AHCI : AHCI
```

It's been a while since I have done a computer build and clearly there are many new features. I assumed that the installation would be backwards compatible and all I would need to do is use Legacy settings. I tried that. Obviously not that simple. (I also tried UEFI and obviously that didn't work either)

I have read that the Intel chipset doesn't support integrated graphics under legacy. Is that right?

I would like to avoid doing a re-install of CentOS 7 as I have some software installed that takes a long time to install and it is important to maintain it's current state.

Comment: The i5-12400 CPU was released in 2022, it contains a 
Intel UHD Graphics 730 which requires according to some info I found kernel 5.8. So I won't expect that this new hardware works with your old installation.

Comment: Generally, regardless of OS, transferring an OS drive from one machine to another with different hardware is not a good idea due to hardware drivers. Windows has a way to do so via `SysPrep /Generalize` - does Linux not have something similar?

Comment: For Linux you just need a "fallback" initramfs (which consists of essentially all drivers that *might* be be needed to get the "real root" mounted). Since most distros do not rely on the fallback EFI executable path, you'll also need to register the bootloader to the new UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I fear the answer may be that you have to reinstall CentOS 7.

I'm not an expert but I've helped people migrating from old computer to new ones. When I do that, I first check with a live CD that the new hardware works well with the OS I want to install before installing it. New hardware often add stuff that old OS are not able to deal with. Since the last version of CentOS 7 was in 2020-09-29 and i5-12400 was released in January 2022, you may be in that situation...

The other reason may be that CentOS is not able to run with a new processor: that's not like just using a new hard disk. I've never tried to just "copy past" the OS and hope it will work. In fact, I've usually been advised against it. I think the reason is that during installation you get lots of files configured to works with the hardware that are quite never updated later. The only thing I think you can do to save time is to get a list of the packages you've installed so you can reinstall them more quickly.

You wrote "I have some software installed that takes a long time to install and it is important to maintain it's current state.". Maybe you could try to see if there is a way to avoid the full complex re-installation of this software on a new installed CentOS 7?
Another option would be to transfer your old installation on a virtual machine running in a minimal OS on your "new" computer.

Good luck anyway. I hope somebody can provide you a better answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live environment and set up a `chroot` then
`update-initramfs && update-grub`